# PHP NuSoap: how to generate wsdl without xsi:type="xsd:string"

Tags: php, wsdl, nusoap

I used PHP NuSoap to create a wsdl file. This File below:

```
<soapenv:Body>
      <loc:register soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <msisdn xsi:type="xsd:string">?</msisdn>
         <packagecode xsi:type="xsd:string">?</packagecode>
         <username xsi:type="xsd:string">?</username>
         <password xsi:type="xsd:string">?</password>
         <channel xsi:type="xsd:string">?</channel>
         <info xsi:type="xsd:string">?</info>
      </loc:register>
   </soapenv:Body>
```

But I want to generate without this string xsi:type="xsd:string"

```
<soapenv:Body>
          <loc:register>
             <msisdn>?</msisdn>
             <packagecode>?</packagecode>
             <username>?</username>
             <password>?</password>
             <channel>?</channel>
             <info>?</info>
          </loc:register>
       </soapenv:Body>
```

Thanks in regard.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar challenge and hope my answer might help someone.

While registering your method, add literal as below:

```
$server->register("GetHelloWorld", 
 array('name' => 'xsd:string'),       
   array('return' => 'xsd:string'),   
    'urn:helloworld',           
    'urn:helloworld#GetHelloWorld',   
    'rpc',         
    'literal'    //add this to your register method
);
```